# How can I call a ruleset within another ruleset?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've just added a simple darkmode function to my website, and I'm wondering if there is a way to override the `filter:` property from `.wrapper .profile .contacts{}`, within the ruleset `.dark-mode{}`?

Since I use the filter on some .svg-files, I want to override it to `filter: none;`. Is it possible to do something like:

```css
.dark-mode {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(9, 12, 16, 1) 0%, rgba(15, 20, 27, 1) 100%);
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #090C10;

  .contacts {
  filter: none;
  }
}
```

My code is listed underneath:

**Javascript:**

```js
function darkModeFunc() {
  let element = document.body;
  element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
}
```

**CSS:**

```css
html, body {
  background: #eeeeee;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #ffffff 0%, #adadad 100%);
  color: black;
  font-family: "Dosis";
  margin: 0;
}

.dark-mode {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(9, 12, 16, 1) 0%, rgba(15, 20, 27, 1) 100%);
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #090C10;
  
}
.wrapper .profile .contacts {
  list-style: none;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  filter: invert(100%) sepia(0%) saturate(7500%) hue-rotate(23deg) brightness(118%) contrast(118%);
}
```

Comment: It's `.dark-mode .wrapper .profile .contacts{filter: none;}` You have to be more specific than the selector that is applying the filter in the first place. Css does not support nesting selectors as in your example. Css precompilers like sass can do what you propose

Comment: The problem is, that I want to apply the ruleset `.dark-mode` to the whole body, instead of the specific class `.contacts`...

Comment: You do both. What you have for the body and the rule that I suggested.

Comment: I was hoping for another solution, since there is other elements which needs to be overrided. But how would you implement the  `.dark-mode .wrapper .profile .contacts` ruleset, in the js function?

Comment: Look at this. https://jsfiddle.net/x9dvpfhb/ That issue that you're having is why sass was invented. Css is very repeteitive as a language. Look at how sites like stack overflow and discord implement a dark mode. They use custom css properties to store the values that need to be changed when dark mode is triggered, then instead of changing arbitrary elements burrowed all through the dom, they only have to change the properties on body.

Comment: Oh okay, that makes sense. I'm gonna look more into sass then.
Thank you!

Comment: You can always override your CSS as long as if it's loaded after the current css code. Which would simply mean that you put it after your .wrapper .profile .contacts tag in your css file.
On top of that you can use !important to force override. This is not recommended to be used though.